# Big_int factorial exception

Tags: ocaml

I've tried to implement factorial using Big_int, utop can evaluate it, but it fails in run time. Here is the code:

```
let factorial (num : int) =
  let n = Big_int.big_int_of_int num in
  let rec fac (n : Big_int.big_int) : Big_int.big_int =
  if n = Big_int.zero_big_int then Big_int.unit_big_int
  else Big_int.mult_big_int n (fac (Big_int.sub_big_int n Big_int.unit_big_int)) in
  fac n
```

How to fix this case? What is the right (and short) way of implementing factorial using Big_int? 
Run this code: factorial 3;;
Error output:

```
Exception: (Invalid_argument "compare: abstract value").
Raised by primitive operation at file "//toplevel//", line 4, characters 5-29
Called from file "//toplevel//", line 5, characters 30-80
Called from file "//toplevel//", line 5, characters 30-80
Called from file "//toplevel//", line 5, characters 30-80
Called from file "toplevel/toploop.ml", line 180, characters 17-56
```

Comment: Calculating factorials using recursion should be reserved for learning exercises.  The right way to do it would using the gamma function and memoization.

Comment: What does the error message say? How do you call `factorial`?

Comment: @duffymo Interesting... How does one avoid precision loss when using the gamma function? Or is there a way to compute it without using floating-point numbers?

Comment: gamma function does use floating point numbers; integer values are a special case.  You have a better chance of getting large values correct with doubles.  It's tailor made for formulas like binomial, etc.

Comment: @duffymo Is there a way to *precisely* compute, say `1000!`, using the gamma function and memoization without taking "chances"? A link to a paper would suffice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Chances?  I'm not sure I know what you mean.  This is a fact: gamma(n+1) = n!.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html.  Memoization just means "hang onto expensive values rather than throwing them away".  It's caching.  I see no risk in any of this.  Numerical Recipes shows how to calculate ln(gamma).

Comment: @duffymo (1) One usually computes the gamma function using floating-point numbers. (2) I know what memoization means. (3) We can easily loose precision while computing the gamma function, and for 1000! get a natural number which is close to the precise answer, but is not exactly equal to it. (4) I'd like to get a proof of your claim (or a link to such proof). (5) I'm not the OP, so could you mention me in your answers   so I'd get notifications, please? Thanks.

Comment: Proof?  See the link to Wolfram Alpha - he's a better mathematician than I am.  Worried about precision?  By all means, cast to an int.  I doubt that 1000! will be worried about the fractional parts.

Comment: @duffymo, an _exact_ value of a factorial function can be computed only with iteration or recursion. Although it is indeed a fact that Г(n+1) = n!, the Г function itself is not computable, as it requires integration from 0 to infinity (see the definition). So, every implementation of the Г-function is an approximation (e.g., Lancoz approximation), and an error usually is much bigger than 1.

Comment: Not computable?  Of course it is.  Indefinite integrals can be calculated.  There's a function to calculate ln(gamma) in Numerical Recipes.  I had the 2nd edition of that book in 1991.  The function was probably available in the 1st edition before that.  Yes, it's an approximation, but it's good enough.

Comment: See the definition for gamma?  I'm the one that introduced it into this conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this comparison `n = Big_int.zero_big_int`. If you change it to using the `Big_int`'s function for comparing `big_int`s -- `eq_big_int`, then everything should work.

Here is another example of implementing this function that uses tail-recursion:

```
open Big_int

let factorial (num : int) : big_int =
  let rec fac_big_int n acc =
    if n = 0 then acc
    else fac_big_int (pred n)
                     (mult_big_int (big_int_of_int n)
                                   acc)
  in
    fac_big_int num unit_big_int
```

A test in `utop`:

```
μ> #load "nums.cma";;
μ> #use "fact_big_int.ml";;
val factorial : int -> big_int = <fun>
μ> string_of_big_int (factorial 10);;
- : string = "3628800"
μ> string_of_big_int (factorial 30);;
- : string = "265252859812191058636308480000000"
```